# Image placed outside of container creating unwanted space

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I can't seem to get things as I want and it's driving me nuts, so please help if you can!
I want this cmc image to be placed a little outside of its container/textarea, but it makes all this space that I would really want to get rid off. The html I've used is this:

```
<img style="position: relative; top: -200px; left: 780px; z-index; 1; width: 220px; height: 220px;" src="http://live-it.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cmc-note.png" alt="CMC - Portfolio" />
```

If you have ANY suggestions, please let me know! I'm new to this whole thing, so it would be very much appreciated!

The link to my site: live-it.dk

Comment: cant help without examples, code etc

Comment: Yea, sorry, I just tried to add a screenshot but it won't let me. The link to the site is live-it.dk

Comment: You probably want to use absolute positioning on the image instead of relative. Relative will leave space for the element and then move it, while absolute won't.

Comment: What part of your site is having this error?

Comment: But then the position is wrong when viewing on big screens and in different browsers? That's the problem, cause I started to go with absolute.

Comment: The first page, the home page "forside". It's the image that says "CMC".

Comment: Try my edit on my answer.

Comment: @CarinaMurielConradsen, it is courteous to accept an answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:absolute`. Relative positioning maintains the original whitespace taken by the element. When you absolutely position it. The element is removed from the flow of the document and placed where you specify, the whitespace is then collapsed. You will also have to alter your `left` and `top` with this though

```
<img style="position: absolute; top: -200px; left: 780px; z-index; 1; width: 220px; height: 220px;" src="http://live-it.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cmc-note.png" alt="CMC - Portfolio" />
```

Comment: But when I'm using absolute, then on big screens it won't be at the right position any longer?

Comment: @CarinaMurielConradsen When you position with pixels, the positioning should be roughly accurate. You will run into issues on very small screens. In that case you should start using fluid layouts (making your positioning with percentages of their context). Do this for your positioning, height, and width and your site will look more proportional.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
<img style="position: relative; top: -200px; left: 780px; z-index; 1; width: 220px; height: 220px;" src="http://live-it.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cmc-note.png" alt="CMC - Portfolio" />
```

to

```
<img style="position: absolute; top: 110px; left: 1310px; z-index; 1; width: 220px; height: 220px;" src="http://live-it.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cmc-note.png" alt="CMC - Portfolio">
```

should work

EDIT:
Try this

```
<img style="width: 220px; height: 220px; float: right; margin-top: -210px; margin-right: -89px;" src="http://live-it.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cmc-note.png" alt="CMC - Portfolio">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! Now it is just not working well on mobile devices :/

Comment: @CarinaMurielConradsen For small devices look into CSS media queries. There you can set specific positions/dimensions for elements when the screen gets smaller than a specified size

Comment: @CarinaMurielConradsen, as gibsonman said you will need to use media queries to make it look better on mobile devices (which is a new question altogether)